# chef recipe unable install nginx on RHEL 7.3

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, rhel7

I am trying use the package manager in chef and installing nginx server but every time i ran the cook book on my client it is just saying that

```
 Recipe: nginx::default
```

* yum_package[nginx] action install[2017-03-11T06:16:01-05:00] INFO: Processing yum_package[nginx] action install (nginx::default line 11)

```
 * No candidate version available for nginx
 ================================================================================
 Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[nginx]'
 ================================================================================

 Chef::Exceptions::Package
 -------------------------
 No candidate version available for nginx

 Resource Declaration:
 ---------------------
 # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb

  11: package "nginx" do
  12:   action :install
  13: end
  14:

 Compiled Resource:
 ------------------
 # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/nginx/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'

 yum_package("nginx") do
   package_name "nginx"
   action [:install]
   retries 0
   retry_delay 2
   default_guard_interpreter :default
   declared_type :package
   cookbook_name "nginx"
   recipe_name "default"
   flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
 end

 Platform:
 ---------
 x86_64-linux
```

[2017-03-11T06:16:29-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers:
 [2017-03-11T06:16:29-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
 Running handlers complete
 [2017-03-11T06:16:29-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
 Chef Client failed. 1 resources updated in 05 minutes 44 seconds

And even i tried to install epel-release packages but denied with similar errors.

Any idea how we could install nginx with CHEF recipe.

I tried also using yum_package but had no luck in installing

```
 yum_package "nginx" do
    action :install
 end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This means there is no package named `nginx` in your repositories. If you log into the machine you want to provision (With `kitchen login`, for example), you can try to search package nginx.

The best way to install it if it is not in your repositories is either adding [nginx´s official repo](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) with a chef repository resource (Like yum_repository for Centos) or downloading the tarball with Chef resource `remote_file`.

If you choose the last option, be sure to generate a sha256 of the tarball you download and add it to the `remote_file` resource, so among other things you prevent Chef from downloading every run the file.

-Edit-

As Szymon says, you can also use the Nginx cookbook for this and don't write any special recipe.

Comment: To be honest, there is no need to write any code to handle repository. Official chef_nginx cookbook [can handle this](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef_nginx/blob/master/recipes/package.rb). Just read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

As [discussed here](https://serverfault.com/a/990347/546997), you can use official NGINX chef cookbook or just install `epel-release` before installing NGINX:

```rb
if platform_family?('rhel')
  package 'epel-release'
end

if platform_family?('debian')
  apt_update 'update'
end

package 'nginx'
```